# PostgreSQL exceptionally slow parsing of extremely short queries

Tags: parsing, postgresql, logging, performance

I'm using Zend Framework (PHP) and postgresql as the session storage backend. Sometimes I'm getting tons of logs like this:

```
Mar  8 11:07:00 myhost postgres[79149]: [30640132-1] 0 LOG:  00000: duration: 1401.742 ms  parse pdo_stmt_00000005: SELECT "sessions".* FROM "php"."sessions" WHERE ((("sessions"."id" = '3d5tmqutaeuivtf8a1udfa5i04')))
Mar  8 11:07:00 myhost postgres[79150]: [30640151-1] 0 LOG:  00000: duration: 1400.083 ms  parse pdo_stmt_00000007: SELECT "sessions".* FROM "php"."sessions" WHERE ((("sessions"."id" = 'b2vh1r29vnqg1e3600ther40c3')))
Mar  8 11:07:00 myhost postgres[79152]: [30640135-1] 0 LOG:  00000: duration: 1401.261 ms  parse pdo_stmt_00000005: SELECT "sessions".* FROM "php"."sessions" WHERE ((("sessions"."id" = '3d5tmqutaeuivtf8a1udfa5i04')))
Mar  8 11:07:00 myhost postgres[79147]: [30640166-1] 0 LOG:  00000: duration: 1381.648 ms  parse pdo_stmt_00000009: SELECT "sessions".* FROM "php"."sessions" WHERE ((("sessions"."id" = '6uj0955g64mmd9i8ra1q5nbtd5')))
```

Table php.sessions has about 500-1000 rows at any moment.

It seems strange, as the execution of this statement was not logged as slow, but the parsing is almost "endless".

Any clue? Does anyone know of any postgres query parser speed issues?

Some tech background:

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.9 on CentOS 6.0, It's 2x 10Core Intel machine with 128 GB RAM. Cpu is was used only 20% - 25% at this very time. Disk reads/writes are extremely fast. log_min_statement = 500

Comment: Locks on the catalogs? lack of shared_buffers ? Try to look at the locklists, maybe use prepared statements.

Comment: I've `shared_buffers = 32GB`. I cannot use prepared statements in this case. And sadly don't know how to monitor locks online. This happens few times a day, and often comes by without me even noticing it.

Comment: Beats me. Maybe you should *lower* shared_mem ;-)

Comment: Thanks anyway. I don't think lowering shared_buffers is a good idea... It's a huge database with near realtime access requirement. I suppose that there are some locks preventing pgsql from running smoothly.

Comment: Could also be some other restricted resource acting as a funnel / hotspot. At least the parser is a (reasonable) harmless place to wait.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a different environment?

Comment: Your shared buffers at 32GB seems far to huge...shared buffers determines how much the server will use to hold requests that are awaiting attention from the kernel buffer and CPU, 32 GB is far to large, I'd scale that back to 64MB for the time being.   It seems the queries you are showing here are really small one line queries while you've optimized your DB for overtly large queries only.

Comment: Decent optimization site to read : http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/Tidbits/perf.html#wal    This value should be set based on the dataset size which the database server is supposed to handle at peak loads and on your available RAM (keep in mind that RAM used by other applications on the server is not available). We recommend following rule of thumb for this parameter:

Start at 4MB (512) for a workstation
Medium size data set and 256-512MB available RAM: 16-32MB (2048-4096)
Large dataset and lots of available RAM (1-4GB): 64-256MB (8192-32768)

Comment: shared_buffers works best when ~ 20 to 25% of available RAM, with a max of 8GB on Linux. But you have to test for you situation. 4MB is a very strange idea, the database will almost never have data in the buffers, there is no space. This also has a huge impact on all queryplans, they suck.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Setting shared_buffers to anything below 16GB causes the DB to choke. Doesn't seem like a bottleneck. Database consists of more than 100 millions rows spread around few dozens of tables. I've more than 1000 transactions per second in peak and cannot afford to wait parsing. It's just DB server, nothing more running. I cannot replicate it. Restoring the dump lasts forever, and I hardly can simulate everyday DB utilization.
@Twelfth - it's article from 2003... I've read many articles and books like this for at least past two years, but thanx :)

Comment: Just came up with an idea. But need confirmation. Does parsing require work_mem? I've it set to 128MB. I've lots of joins/lookups/sorts, and maybe the parser needs to wait becasue of lack of this kind of buffers???

Comment: First of all - NOPE, workmem is not for parsing ;) Secondly just to clarify -> in most of theese cases only CPU system time is higher.

Answer (score 3):

This case appeared to be: lots of long idle'ing transactions, i.e. **<IDLE> in transaction**. We've managed to get rid of most of them. And the result is outstanding.

The main reason sadly occured to be flawed application logic. I mean that part of the transactions looked like:

- **begin**
- **query**
- **query**
- wait
- ... (lots of waiting)
- wait
- **commit**

As the row versioning subsystem has had to keep lots of old versions of the rows, the system has been becoming less and less responsive (each simple query has had to look for appropriate row versions).

Comment: Good old locks.  Best to keep your session lookups in a different db transaction then.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation on a test box in cases when:

- CPU-heavy processes are run on the server;
- Systems starts swapping out RAM onto disks for RAM-intensive processes.

PostgreSQL relies on 2 layers of data caches:

1. shared pool, specified via `shared_buffers`;
2. OS cache, specified via `effective_cache_size`, could you tell us what's your value here, please?

In order to understand what is really going on your system, you should monitor:

- CPU usage;
- RAM usage;
- IO and swap volumes.

By *monitor* I mean not just looking at the current values, but rather using tools like `sar`, `iostat`, `vmstat` and alike, combined with, say, [RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) for better data analysis. And then review produced reports for time period you observe unwanted delays in simple queries.

I have a feeling that you are having IO issues, but cannot tell more without looking at the system and reports.

I would recommend:

1. Setup monitoring and review produced reports;
2. Create a Standby database on a similar box in order to play around with different settings. (I assume you have proper database and WAL backups to do that.) I would look into: memory, autovacuum, checkpoints and WAL settings.
3. Consider upgrading to the PostgreSQL 9.1, you're 2 major releases behind.

Comment: 1) this machine is dedicated for PostgreSQL
2) no RAM swapping
3) lots of buffers and cache
4) monitoring it all
5) constantly improving query plans :)
6) neither copy nor upgrade is not considerable due to live requirement
I've already come up with the answer. I'll write it in minutes.